# maximum call stack size exceeded error in chrome using jquery templates

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-templates

I'm loading more than 7000 records and displaying them on my page.

Firefox is doing just fine but I'm having an error using Chrome

Partial code:

```
<tbody>
    {{each(i, item) value}}
    <tr>
        <td class="item_action">
            <a class="edit_item" data-item="${item.id}">
                <img src="path/to/image_edit.png" />
            </a>

            <img src="path/to/image_separator.png" />

            <a class="delete_item" data-item="${item.id}">
                <img src="path/to/image_delete.png" />
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="item_name">${item.name}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

If instead of the above I render this:

```
<tbody>
    {{each(i, item) value}}
    <tr>
        <td class="item_name">${item.name}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Then Chrome has no problem. So I guess it has something to do with the size of HTML I'm trying to render as I've read [here](http://shareddev.blogspot.com.ar/2011/11/javascript-maximum-call-stack-size.html).

Is there a solution for this issue? I

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue. If you look to jquery.tmpl code you can find

```
function build( tmplItem, nested, content ) { ...
```

The problem is in

```
jQuery.map( content, function( item ) {
```

for each item in the 'content' array (and you have i guess more than 50000 elements here) should be called function. This is too much for Webkit browsers. 
This code was modified a little to solve my issue:

```
function build( tmplItem, nested, content ) {
    // Convert hierarchical content into flat string array
    // and finally return array of fragments ready for DOM insertion
    var processMap = function(){
        var result = [];
        var items = [];
        for(var i = 0; i<content.length; (i = i+10000)){
            var subcontent = content.slice(i, i+10000);
            items =  jQuery.map( subcontent, function( item ) {
                        return (typeof item === "string") ?
                            // Insert template item annotations, to be converted to jQuery.data( "tmplItem" ) when elems are inserted into DOM.
                            (tmplItem.key ? item.replace( /(<\w+)(?=[\s>])(?![^>]*_tmplitem)([^>]*)/g, "$1 " + tmplItmAtt + "=\"" + tmplItem.key + "\" $2" ) : item) :
                            // This is a child template item. Build nested template.
                            build( item, tmplItem, item._ctnt );
            });
            result = result.concat(items);
        }
        return result;
    };
    var frag, ret = content ?  processMap():
    // If content is not defined, insert tmplItem directly. Not a template item. May be a string, or a string array, e.g. from {{html $item.html()}}.
    tmplItem;
    if ( nested ) {
        return ret;
    } ...
```

So jQuery.map function process each 10000 elements and doesn't allow 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'.

This is a crude solution but hope it helps you :)

Comment: this solution worked for me, but i have to change the stack size to 500.

Comment: thanks for the solution. This helped to get rid of that error. But the code is running very slow for huge data. Seems like they have moved to jsrender. But I just tried to do normal javascript string concatenation for my sceneario and it seems to be lightning fast.